# SignalR functions are not working after publish in Azure Gov App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, azure-web-app-service, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have implemented SignalR in my application and it worked fine in On-prem, once I publish it in Azure Gov SignalR call from server to client is not working always. Especially with IE brewer SignalR calls are not working for most of the times. In Chrome sometimes it is not working

**Client Code**

```
$(function () {

        var ccuHub = $.connection.alertHub;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log('start error: ' + error);
        });

        if (window.location.pathname == baseUrl + "Home/UserLogin" && $('#inpHdnUserconcurrentUserID').val() != undefined) {
            concurrentUserId = $('#inpHdnUserconcurrentUserID').val();
        }

        ccuHub.client.ForceLogOut = function (connectionId) {
            if (connectionId != concurrentUserId) {
                //  alert('Not Matched concurrentUserId' + concurrentUserId);
                Utility.showMessage(resourceList.ConcurrentUser_Warning_SameUserLoggedInAnother, Utility.MessageType.Warning);

                var onSuccessLoginLogOut = function () {
                    window.location.href = baseUrl + "Login/Index?returnUrl=Y"
                };

                Utility.makeAjaxCall("Login/Logout", "POST", JSON.stringify({ concurrentUserID: concurrentUserId }), onSuccessLoginLogOut, null, null, false);
                //$.connection.hub.stop();
            }
        };
    });
```

**Server Code**

```
[HttpGet]
    public void ConcurrentUserLogOut(string connectionId)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Info($"ConcurrentUserLogOut-ConnectionID:{connectionId}");
            IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlertHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.ForceLogOut(connectionId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error on ConcurrentUserLogOut , connection Id : " + connectionId + " Error :" + ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Is there anything need to done specially for Azure? Also SignalR methods are taking too much of time in Azure, app become very slow.**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Everything works fine for me until I publish my client to Azure.